# Configure VSCode and Android Studio coding style setting

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Issue: Me and my other developer are working a large project. Some developer like Android Studio and some developer like VS Code. So when developer clone code at that time many files are auto change formate as per the IDE.

Code Language: Dart(Flutter)

OS: Mac

IDE: Android Studio and VS Code.

So any one help me on both of IDE coding style setting.

Thank you for advance.